# Store authentication token in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to store authentication token, that i received from log-in response.

It is right to use for this NSUserDefaults? Or I must use KeyChainWrapper?

What is the best way store authentication token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safer to store them in the Keychain (btw. https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security is awesome).

Comment: +1 for SFHFKeychainUtils, they make the keychain a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone) on GitHub:

```
[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:aUsername andPassword:aPassword forServiceName:@"MyService"  updateExisting:TRUE error:&anError];
```

there is also `getPasswordForUsername` and `deleteItemForUsername`

edit- and cortez has provided link in his answer

Answer (score 0):

@Akshay,
NSUserDefaults is not the way to go at all... As soon as you delete the app from the iphone the NSUserDefaults entries get lost and won't be available after that again. KeyChain is much much safer for that kind of need.

Sebastian

Answer (score -3):

`NSUserDefaults` is the way to go. It is the simplest.